# How can I make emacs indentation behaviour like phpstorm/eclipse?

Tags: emacs, indentation

I'm  new to emacs and trying desperately to make it behave the way I've gotten used to over the last few years with my IDEs.

I love a lot of the stuff it's doing but I am taking issue with its indentation practices.

What I want:

- 4 spaces instead of tab
- Pressing enter to put the cursor on the same column as where the previous line starts
- Pressing tab inserts 4 spaces regardless of whatever the 'smart' indentation might think is correct
- Pressing tab when using neotree-dir should try to resolve the path normally

I've managed to get 2/4 with https://github.com/zorgnax/regtab.
Unfortunately, that solution breaks the path resolve in neotree.

EDIT: Thought it would make sense to show my .emacs config for this

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/")
(load "regtab.el")
(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-regtab-mode regtab-mode
  (lambda() (regtab-mode 1)))
(my-global-regtab-mode 1)
(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode -1))
```

Electric-indent-mode is turned off because if I indent a line in what it thinks is an 'invalid way', and then press RET, it 'corrects' my indentation. It does the same thing for the whole file when I use C-y

The reason you would want to make 'invalid' indentation is that certain libraries use what is essentially invalid html/js syntax.

EDIT2:
Replacing

```
(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode -1))
```

with

```
(setq-default electric-indent-inhibit t)
```

has sort of helped. It no longer forces weird indentation onto me but now it at least indents somewhat when pressing RET and no longer ruins my indents when using C-y.

What's left now is to somehow achieve what regtab does without screwing up  path resolve for M-x commands.

Answer (score 0):

Alright well, I kinda figured out my own stuff. If you have better solutions than what I'm about to list, please supply them.

1) Fixing crappy emacs indents:
Get this file: https://github.com/zorgnax/regtab
Put it in ~/.emacs.d/plugins/ (this file doesn't exist, make it.)

In your ~/.emacs file, add this:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/")
(load "regtab.el")
(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-regtab-mode regtab-mode
  (lambda() (regtab-mode 1)))
(my-global-regtab-mode 1)
(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode -1))
(setq-default electric-indent-inhibit t)
```

2) Fixing side effects of the previous steps:
Install hippie-expand
Add the following to your ~/.emacs file

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-/") 'my-expand-file-name-at-point)
(defun my-expand-file-name-at-point ()
  "Use hippie-expand to expand the filename"
  (interactive)
  (let ((hippie-expand-try-functions-list '(try-complete-file-name-partially try-complete-file-name)))
    (call-interactively 'hippie-expand)))
```

Now, when you want to complete a path in your M-x commands, use C-M-/